# formatting string date into mysql date

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, date

I've been reading threads here on how to format the string date probably, however it wont add the date. Instead it just adds 0000-00-00. How come it wont format the string date?

the $date variable could for instance be equal to 10/10/2014

```
    $date = str_replace('.', '-', $undate);
    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    $newdate = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO " . $your_db_name . "
        (date, time, hometeam, awayteam, score)
         VALUES ($newdate, '$time', '$opp1', '$opp2', '$score')");
```

Comment: The problem you describe is a typical example of SQL injection that shows why creating SQL queries with string concatenation and variable interpolation has such a probelmatic history and present: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already got the correct date format `Y-m-d`, those needed to be quoted as well:

```
VALUES ('$newdate', '$time', '$opp1', '$opp2', '$score')
```

With @hakre's suggestion on the comment below. It also has a prepared statement wrapper, might as well use it for safer queries:

```
$prepared_statement = $wpdb->prepare("
    INSERT INTO $your_db_name
        (date, time, hometeam, awayteam, score)
        VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s )
    ", 
    $newdate 
    $time, 
    $opp1,
    $opp2,
    $score
);

$wpdb->query($prepared_statement);
```

If this `$your_db_name` (most likely a table name) is a user input as well, you need to whitelist this as you cannot bind table names. A simple `in_array()` with predefined table names should suffice.

Comment: Psst, this is Wordpress: [WPDB - Protect Queries Against SQL Injection Attacks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks)